# Is it possible to run different Erlang OTP version at the same time?

Tags: ios, erlang, apple-push-notifications, erlang-otp

I am trying to add Apple's voip push notification into our app. Our backend provider is written by Erlang's Ejabberd server with apns4erl server 1.0.4.

Currently, the apns4erl 2 has the capability to send voip push notification. But it require OTP 19+ to compile and our system is running on OTP 17.3.

So may I know is that possible to run these two OTP at the same time? I can't upgrade OTP to 19+. And new library require 19+.

Are there good way to make this requirement possible or I need to porting the new library into our old one?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Btw, I saw your profile. Taiwan? "Hello!" from next door -- I'm in Okinawa! `(^.^)/`

Comment: Thanks your help. I will try it. I am a newbie of Erlang, too many things need to learn. Really thank for your help. ^_^..  Okinawa is a good place, many of my friends like there, but I have never been there yet. Hope some day I can go there with my family for a vocation.

Comment: Recently, I found a new way to connect to the existing node.The option -remsh can do the same things, ex: erl -sname client -remsh ejabberd@new server-api-001

Comment: `-remsh` connects a remote shell on startup, but does not ensure version compatibility. Use the `+R` option mentioned in legoscia's answer together with `-remsh` to ensure compatibility with an older version. I'm unsure whether `-remsh` can be passed multiple times (to start, say, 3 shell sessions on different nodes at once).

Comment: Thanks，I will do more study about the compatibility issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Keep in mind while reading this that you should **really** find a way to update your existing service to keep up to date with newer runtimes. I've dealt with being stuck on a legacy runtime only because someone thought they needed to fork a particular module somewhere in a way that made it impossible to upgrade -- and that was just a nightmare.*

## TL;DR: (But you should read it anyway)

Yes, I just confirmed that you *can* connect an R17 and an R20 node via disterl and send messages:

R17 node:

```
ceverett@changa:/opt/erlang/R17.5/bin$ ./erl -name bar -cookie walnut
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)
(bar@changa.shinden.tsuriai.jp)1> P = spawn(fun Wait() -> receive {From, Message} -> From ! {received, Message}, Wait() end end).
<0.44.0>
(bar@changa.shinden.tsuriai.jp)2> global:register_name(waiter, P).
yes
```

R20 node:

```
ceverett@changa:~$ erl -name foo -cookie walnut                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Erlang/OTP 20 [RELEASE CANDIDATE 2] [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Eshell V9.0  (abort with ^G)
(foo@changa.shinden.tsuriai.jp)1> net_kernel:connect('bar@changa.shinden.tsuriai.jp').
true
(foo@changa.shinden.tsuriai.jp)2> global:send(waiter, {self(), "blah blah blah"}).
<7489.44.0>
(foo@changa.shinden.tsuriai.jp)3> flush().
Shell got {received,"blah blah blah"}
ok
```

Note that above the R20 node was started *first*, so that was the version of EPMD that was running. I have no idea whether that would matter, nor do I know if EPMD has changed between R17 and R20.

This is *all undocumented functionality*. Read below for a *much* more future-proof way to do this.

The documented way to connect two nodes of different versions is with the `+R` runtime flag. I regard this as a wildly unreliable hack (precisely as unreliable as what I demonstrated above) unless you've tested it thoroughly first -- and it may have unintended side effects depending on the versions involved (and no telling what is coming in the future). But *this is an actual runtime flag* and it obviously exists for a reason. See [legoscia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801836/is-it-possible-to-run-different-erlang-otp-version-at-the-same-time/46807036#46807036) for more detail about this.

## Discussion

Whether or not two versions of Erlang's runtime are compatible over disterl, writing network applications in Erlang is *really easy*. You can always connect two of any different things over TCP.

The simple solution to this would be to write a network application in Erlang using the current version of Erlang (R20.1 at the moment) that receives Apple voip pushes, and forwards them to your main application.

Write:

- A single TCP socket handling process inside your R17 system.
- The Apple VOIP push service handler in R20 and a TCP socket connecting process that talks to the R17 TCP socket handler.

Treat the Apple VOIP service within your system *as if it exists as a native part of your application*. The socket handler in the R17 node *is* the VOIP service. Make sure you write its interface functions with that in mind -- later if you can migrate your code to R20 then you won't have to worry with this detail because it will be already abstracted by the internal protocol in Erlang.

As for the push updates themselves, you can create whatever sort of protocol you want.

Erlang's [external term format](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html) has not changed between R17 and R20, so you will be able to send native messages between the two nodes by having the Apple VOIP side socket handler (on the R20 node) do something like:

```
notify_node(Socket, VOIP_Data) ->
    Message = term_to_binary({push, VOIP_Data}),
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, Message),
    log(info, "Message sent").
```

And on the receiving node (the R17 node):

```
loop(Parent, Debug, State = #s{socket = Socket}) ->
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->
            {push, VOIP_Data} = binary_to_term(Bin, [safe]),
            {ok, NewState} = do_stuff(VOIP_Data, State)
            loop(Parent, Debug, NewState);
        %% Your other stuff
        %% OTP system stuff
    end.
```

You could write the R17 side as a gen_server also, listening for:

```
handle_info({tcp, Socket, Bin}, State = #s{socket = Socket}) ->
    %% whatever
```

I just happen to most often see socket handling processes as `proc_lib` processes instead of gen_servers most of the time. But it doesn't matter in most cases.

Another approach is to use binaries:

```
notify_node(Socket, VOIP_Data) ->
    Message = <<"PUSH ", VOIP_Data>>,
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, Message),
    log(info, "Message sent").
```

And on the receiving node (the R17 node):

```
loop(Parent, Debug, State = #s{socket = Socket}) ->
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, <<"PUSH ", VOIP_Data/binary>>} ->
            {ok, NewState} = do_stuff(VOIP_Data, State)
            loop(Parent, Debug, NewState);
        %% Your other stuff
        %% OTP system stuff
    end.
```

It really depends on the nature of `VOIP_Data`. If it is a binary itself and the R20 Apple push service should just pass it along without inspecting it, then the raw binary method is easy. If the R20 side is going to be interpreting the message and converting it to an Erlang message of its own then you'll do *much* better with the `binary_to_term/1`/`term_to_binary/2` form.

Comment: Hi zxq9, the RPC code did work for my current problem. But currently, I create the new node on OTP 20.1 and old node on OTP 17.3. Actually, it's work well under my currently testing. The call sending from node 17 to 20 is really simple, just a record data send from OTP17 to OTP 20. But according to your & legoscia's comment, the +R option seems necessary when I create the OTP 20 node. Are there something I can check for the capability issue for my OTP 20 + OTP 17 system?

Answer (score 4):

## Maybe

[zxq9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46802683/113848) shows that it actually works, and also suggests an alternative approach. This answer speaks more generally about connecting two different releases using Erlang distribution.

In [the `erl` man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) you  can find the `+R` flag:

> `+R ReleaseNumber`
> Sets the compatibility mode.
>
> The distribution mechanism is not backward compatible by default. This flag sets the emulator in compatibility mode with an earlier Erlang/OTP release `ReleaseNumber`. The release number must be in the range `<current release>-2..<current release>`. This limits the emulator, making it possible for it to communicate with Erlang nodes (as well as C- and Java nodes) running that earlier release.
>
> **Note**
> Ensure that all nodes (Erlang-, C-, and Java nodes) of a distributed Erlang system is of the same Erlang/OTP release, or from two different Erlang/OTP releases X and Y, where all Y nodes have compatibility mode X.

This mirrors what [the Compatibility section](https://www.erlang.org/doc/system_principles/misc.html#compatibility) of the manual says:

> **Erlang Distribution**
>
> Erlang nodes can communicate across at least two preceding and two subsequent releases.

So in theory Erlang 17 and 19 should be able to communicate if the 19 node is started with the `+R 17` flag.

But in fact this flag currently doesn't turn on any compatibility features (see [the source code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/368715caab1cd1010c2cde0db4959a94afa8153c/erts/emulator/beam/erl_init.c#L2058)), and it hasn't done so since [compatibility for R9 was removed](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/ef302baca81) in R16B.  The answer to whether release X and release Y can connect to each other is "try it and see".

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65082036/113848) for a table showing connectivity between various Erlang releases.