# How do I run a cluster of nodes with both OTP-23.1 and R15B03-1?

Tags: erlang, distributed-system, erlang-otp

I have a cluster of distributed Erlang nodes running [R15B03-1](https://www.erlang.org/downloads/R15B03-1). I have developed new code which I want to release onto new nodes and put them in the current cluster. How do I start my new nodes running version OTP 23.1 in such a way that the distribution protocol between the nodes running R15B03-1 and OTP 23.1 are compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.  Trying to make such a connection results in this error message:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Nov-2020::22:24:57.725297 ===
** new@localhost: Connection attempt from node old@localhost rejected since it cannot handle
   ["BIG_CREATION",
    "UTF8_ATOMS"].**
```

Nodes older than Erlang/OTP <del>20</del> 19 cannot connect to a node running release 23.  In general, backwards compatibility for the distribution protocol is only promised for two major releases in either direction.

---

There is [an option, `+R`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#compat_rel), that sets the "compatibility mode":

> The distribution mechanism is not backward compatible by default. This flag sets the emulator in compatibility mode with an earlier Erlang/OTP release `ReleaseNumber`. The release number must be in the range `<current release>-2..<current release>`.

But in fact this flag currently doesn't turn on any compatibility features (see [the source code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/368715caab1cd1010c2cde0db4959a94afa8153c/erts/emulator/beam/erl_init.c#L2058)), and it hasn't done so since [compatibility for R9 was removed](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/ef302baca81) in R16B.  Anyway, since it only allows going back 2 major releases, R15B and 21 are still too far apart.

The reason this flag doesn't actually control any features is that these days the distribution protocol relies more on feature negotiation. For example, all releases starting with 20 have supported the UTF-8 atom feature in the sense that they would be prepared to use it if another node asked them to do so, but only in release 23 did this feature become mandatory. Thus there is no need for any manual configuration to achieve compatibility within the ±2 major releases ["compatibility window"](https://erlang.org/doc/system_principles/misc.html#:%7E:text=Erlang%20nodes%20can%20communicate%20across,preceding%20and%20two%20subsequent%20releases.&text=Compiled%20code%20can%20be%20loaded,previous%20releases%20is%20not%20supported.&text=Compiled%20HiPE%20code%20can%20be,used%20when%20compiling%20the%20code.).

---

I'd thought I'd test this with an experiment, starting a node using every Erlang version I have installed locally (using ASDF) and making them try to connect to each other:

```sh
erlang_versions=$(asdf list erlang)
for x in $erlang_versions; do
  ~/.asdf/installs/erlang/$x/bin/erl -sname ${x//./-}@localhost -eval '
      timer:sleep(10000),
      {ok, Pairs} = net_adm:names(),
      [io:format("~p ~p ~p~n", [net_adm:ping(list_to_atom(Name++"@localhost")), node(), Name++"@localhost"])
        || {Name, _Port} <- Pairs],
      timer:sleep(10000),
      init:stop()' -noinput &
done
```

The results are in the table below. It seems like release 19 is the earliest release that can connect to release 23.

| Connecting to \ from | R15B03-1 | R16B03 | 17-5-3 | 18-3 | 19-1 | 19-3 | 20-3 | 20-3-8-11 | 21-0 | 21-0-4 | 21-2-2 | 21-3-8-1 | 21-3-8-2 | 22-0-2 | 22-0-4 | 22-0-7 | 22-1-1 | 22-1-2 | 22-2-8 | 22-3 | 22-3-3 | 23-0-2 | 23-0-rc3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R15B03-1 | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no | no |
| R16B03 | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | no | no |
| 17-5-3 | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | no | no |
| 18-3 | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | no | no |
| 19-1 | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 19-3 | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 20-3 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 20-3-8-11 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 21-0 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 21-0-4 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 21-2-2 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 21-3-8-1 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 21-3-8-2 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 22-0-2 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 22-0-4 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 22-0-7 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 22-1-1 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 22-1-2 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 22-2-8 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes | yes |
| 22-3 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes | yes |
| 22-3-3 | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes | yes |
| 23-0-2 | no | no | no | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - | yes |
| 23-0-rc3 | no | no | no | no | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | - |

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Check legoscia's answer, as it's the correct one, I'll leave this here for reference**

You'd need to review the [External Term Format](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html) for possible incompatibilities between both versions with your code (search for `OTP` in that page). I'm not sure what will happen if a node running an old OTP receives some message about some type it does not know.

Maybe it's safer to deploy your current code in OTP23 and then add the new code when all the machines have the same OTP version?

Comment: Can I not use `+R ReleaseNumber` to make sure I am compatible?
https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

Comment: @2240 The `+R` option can only take you back 2 major versions, so 15 and 21 are too far apart. (And in fact this option currently doesn't do anything; I added some details to my answer)